# How do I get primary key object value for a deleted entries using hibernate envers

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-envers

How do I get primary key object value for a deleted entries using hibernate envers?

The following query returns only the updated rows.

```
AuditQuery auditQuery = AuditReaderFactory
                            .get(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession())
                            .createQuery().forEntitiesAtRevision(entity.class, revisionNumber);
```

Comment: Well you are querying for entities at a given revision, and if an entity is deleted before revision `revisionNumber`, then it's not going to show up :)

Comment: I don't want to query by a revision number, but I would want to see all changes made on that object. How should I do that